# How to retrieve contact details for contact in android using LOOKUP KEY?

Tags: android, cursor, android-contacts, loader

I have tried using this code but i'm not able to retrieve the data from onLoadFinished method, i have got cursor.columnCount=7 and cursor.getCount=0. Whenever i'm trying to retrieve data like-
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0])) i'm getting error saying that size 0 and index 0.

```
private static final String[] PROJECTION =
        {
                ContactsContract.Data.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI,
                ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.LABEL,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS
        };
private static final int DETAILS_QUERY_ID = 0;

private static final String SELECTION = ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY + " = ?";
private String[] selectionArgs = { "" };
String lookupKey;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    lookupKey=getArguments().getString("LOOKUPKEY");
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(DETAILS_QUERY_ID, null, this);

}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {
    selectionArgs[0] = lookupKey;

    return new CursorLoader(
            getActivity(),
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            PROJECTION,
            SELECTION,
            selectionArgs,
            null
    );

}
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader) {

}
```

}

Comment: How does your `lookupKey` look like? you might be using a wrong value like a lookupUri or a contactId by mistake

Comment: Lookup key is giving me the same result as contact name

Comment: must be a mistake in that code, post it

Comment: see , here i'm passing the lookup key to details fragment when user click the particular row contact in st view https://github.com/Thesohan/MyContactApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/mycontactapp/ContactsFragment.java

Comment: change `private static final int CONTACT_KEY_INDEX` to 3, not 1. this should represent the index of `LOOKUP_KEY` in your projection array

Comment: also, you don't need `lookupUri`, you should pass `lookupKey`, so don't get confused with that unused variable

Comment: sorry for late reply, Thanks a lot, your second last comment solved my problem, i had changed the CONTACT_KEY_INDEX to 3 and boom, i have got the desired result. you save my day. I was struggling with this problem since last night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'll phrase this an as answer:
your code seems to be correct, but the passed value is not
instead of passing a lookupKey you're passing the contact name to the fragment.

change `private static final int CONTACT_KEY_INDEX` to `3`, not `1`. this should represent the index of `LOOKUP_KEY` in your projection array

Comment: sorry for late reply, Thanks a lot, your second last comment solved my problem, i had changed the CONTACT_KEY_INDEX to 3 and boom, i have got the desired result. you save my day. I was struggling with this problem since last night